# How to cursor-select SVG/d3.js text just like normal HTML text or any other text editor?

Tags: css, html, d3.js, svg

I'm using d3.js to draw a layout graph like this one: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642

But I found that it's very difficult to copy-and-paste the node's label. Take the above link as an example, I can't drag the text to select any sequence. I can only double-click the label to select a certain char sequence.

If I try to select the text with a special char like `Mlle.Vaubois`, I can only get `Mlle` or `Vaubois` selected, I cannot get the whole string `Mlle.Vaubois` selected. (See the below picture)

[image]

Moreover, I can't select arbitrary char sequence inside that string. For example, I can't select the middle two letters: `ll` inside `Mlle.Vaubois`. The highlighting stopped right after the first `l` is selected. (See below:)

[image]

I just want to be able to select any sequence as I want, like in a browser. For example, I can select `rce La` from the HTML text: `Labeled Force Layout` as below. Then I can `Ctrl + C` and `Ctrl + V` as I wish.

[image]

This issue is not just for d3.js, because another more general SVG example also has this issue: http://jsfiddle.net/wPYvS/

[image]

I don't know why SVG handles text selection so different with normal HTML text in a browser or any mainstream text editor? How to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Text selection in an SVG is a lot more complicated than selecting text in a rectangular block in HTML.  SVG characters can be positioned at arbitrary places with arbitrary rotations.  They can follow paths, be clipped and masked and filtered.  I suspect that browsers haven't put very much effort into implementing text selection in SVGs.

Comment: You could consider [manually creating a selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) when a node is clicked on.

Comment: Hi @PaulLeBeau how to do it by manually creating a selection?

Comment: Your link said about how to select HTML text with js. But I need to select SVG label text (in d3.js). I don't know how to do it?

Comment: You can select all the text in a node by double-clicking.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau, you can see my first example in the post, when I double-click on ``Mlle.Vaubois``, I can only get ``Mlle`` or ``Vaubois`` selected. It seems that the selection will be stopped by special chars like ``.``.

Answer (score 3):

The following example adds a click handler to all the "nodes" (ie. `class="node"`), which will select all the text in the node.

```js
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".node");

nodes.forEach( function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener("click", nodeClickHandler);
});

function nodeClickHandler(evt) {
  var selection = document.getSelection();
  var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
  range.selectNode(evt.target);
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="200">
  <g class="node" transform="translate(275.4819543667187,131.9805407488932)">
    <image xlink:href="https://github.com/favicon.ico" x="-8" y="-8" width="16" height="16"> </image>
    <text dx="12" dy=".35em">Mlle.Vaubois</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks. This code works for static svg as in your example, but I can't succeed with it for the dynamic generated svg in js like my example?